# read data from csv file using powershell and strore each line data in an array

Tags: powershell, csv, row

```
#My script is as below 
$empdata = import-csv Log.csv
    ForEach ($Item in $empdata){
    "FirstName = $($empdata.FirstName)
    LastName = $($empdata.LastName)
    Laptop = $($empdata.Laptop)
    AccessCard = $($empdata.AccessCard)
    Phone = $($empdata.Phone)
    Building = $($empdata.Building)
    Location = $($empdata.Location)"
    Write-host $FirstName $LastName $Laptop  $AccessCard $Phone $Building 
    $Location
```

I want to read data of each line into an array and pass it on to another tool, but unable to do so since I am getting data of all columns to together example all data of column 1 appears..

Results are as below

```
FirstName = Suresh Krishna Shiva
LastName = setty Murthy Reddy
Laptop = Lenovo Lenovo Hp
AccessCard = yes No Yes
Phone = 123456789 45678932 12378945
Building = T4 P1 DT14
Location = Chennai Bangalore Hyderabad
FirstName = Suresh Krishna Shiva
LastName = setty Murthy Reddy
Laptop = Lenovo Lenovo Hp
AccessCard = yes No Yes
Phone = 123456789 45678932 12378945
Building = T4 P1 DT14
Location = Chennai Bangalore Hyderabad
FirstName = Suresh Krishna Shiva
LastName = setty Murthy Reddy
Laptop = Lenovo Lenovo Hp
AccessCard = yes No Yes
Phone = 123456789 45678932 12378945
Building = T4 P1 DT14
Location = Chennai Bangalore Hyderabad

I  am trying to get data in the below format


FirstName = Suresh
LastName = setty
Laptop = Lenovo
AccessCard = yes
Phone = 123456789
Building = T4
Location = Chennai
```

Comment: You have your pipeline object as `$Item` but are not using it in the foreach block

Comment: We do not know what is in your CSV file. Please [click here and edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46286784/edit) to include a sample.

Comment: Thanks Matt got it..changed code to FirstName = $($ID.FirstName)

Comment: Note that you get nearly identical output with `Import-Csv Log.csv | Format-List`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#classiq method
import-csv "c:\temp\test.csv" | %{
   "FirstName=$($_.FirstName)"
   "LastName=$($_.LastName)"
   "Phone=$($_.Phone)"
}

#other method with format
import-csv "c:\temp\test.csv" | %{
   "FirstName={0}`nLastName={1}`nPhone={2}" -f $_.FirstName, $_.LastName, $_.Phone
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$empdata = Import-Csv Log.csv

foreach ($item in $empdata) {
    "FirstName = $($item.FirstName)
    LastName = $($item.LastName)
    Laptop = $($item.Laptop)
    AccessCard = $($item.AccessCard)
    Phone = $($item.Phone)
    Building = $($item.Building)
    Location = $($item.Location)"
}
```

`$empdata.FirstName` = the whole `FirstName` column (all rows)

`$item.FirstName` = the `FirstName` value for the current row in your foreach iteration

`$FirstName $LastName $Laptop  $AccessCard $Phone $Building $Location`: these are all null in your example (and not needed to produce the output you want)

Comment: what I would like to get within this `foreach` loop is each row, not column. How can I get each row ($item) as a single object that I can add properties to?

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo `$item` is the row object. You should be able to add properties using `Add-Member` like: `$item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name NewField -Value "duh" -Force`

Comment: Hmmm,, I see. What I'd tried was: `$item.NewField = "duh"`. That didn't work. I guess I'll try `Add-Member` when I have a moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Csv .\Log.csv | ForEach-Object{

    "
        FirstName= $($_.FirstName) `n
        LastName= $($_.LastName)   `n
        Laptop= $($_.Laptop)       `n
        AcessCard= $($_.AcessCard) `n
        Phone= $($_.Phone)         `n
        Building= $($_.Building)   `n
        Location= $($_.Location)
    "
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.